# How can I select values from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to choose values with label '1' at the end and randomly select 1000 comments among the selected values.

[image]

This is the text version of the code that creates the output above:

```
with open('movie_ratings.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
lines = lines[1:]

sentences = [line.split('\t') for line in lines]
sentences
```

Comment: `for line in lines : items =  line.split('\t'); if items[-1]==1; sentences.append(items)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select only sentences where the last element is '1':

```
sentences = [line.split('\t') for line in lines if line.split('\t')[-1] == '1']
```

For the random selection, this can help you on your way: *[Python random.choice() function to select random item from a List and Set](https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/)*

Comment: Thank you!! For now, I have a list of values in a list: 
[ ['8329695', 'the flowers are beautiful.', '1'],
 ['8787592', 'hello.', '1'],
 ['4295337', 'this is interesting.', '1'],
 ['7008696', 'good...', '1'],
...].
How can I select only the values in the middle for tagging? (nltk.pos_tag)

Comment: `[1]` to select the second element in a list (counting starts at 0). So `sentences = [line.split('\t')[1] for line in lines if line.split('\t')[-1] == '1']`

Answer (score 1):

First load in the lines

```
lines = open('movie_ratings.txt').read().splitlines()[1:]
sentences = [line.split('\t') for line in lines]
```

Now we keep comments where that last value is '1'

```
comments_to_keep = [
    comment for rating_id, comment, flag in sentences
    if flag == '1'
]
```

Now we take a sample of those comments

```
import random
sample = random.sample(comments_to_keep, 1000)
```